# How to make a go program recursive

Tags: arrays, recursion, go

How could I make this go program recursive. I'm learning golang by writing a game number analyzer. I've been thinking and thinking on how to do this and can't come up with a working solution. Here is the link in the [Google Playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/lsYjYdEUMN) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/*
File record.go
Author: Dan Huckson
Date: 20160120
Purpose: Number analyzer
*/
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Stats struct {
    category map[string]Events
}

type Events struct {
    event map[string]*Event
}

type Event struct {
    value int64
}

func main() {
    winners := [][]int{
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        {2, 4, 6, 28, 26, 39},
        {1, 4, 9, 10, 26, 39},
        {1, 9, 19, 29, 26, 49},
        {4, 5, 6, 28, 26, 49}}

    keys := []string{"digits1", "digits2", "digits3", "digits4", "digits5", "digits6"}

    stats := new(Stats)
    stats.category = make(map[string]Events)

    for _, key := range keys {
        events, ok := stats.category[key]
        if !ok {
            events = *new(Events)
        }
        events.event = make(map[string]*Event)
        stats.category[key] = events

    }
    fmt.Println()

    for _, winner := range winners {
        fmt.Println(winner)
        stats.digits1("digits1", winner)
        stats.digits2("digits2", winner)
        stats.digits3("digits3", winner)
        stats.digits4("digits4", winner)
        stats.digits5("digits5", winner)
        stats.digits6("digits6", winner)
    }
}

func (stats *Stats) record(key string, balls string) {

    event, ok := stats.category[key].event[balls]
    if !ok {
        event = new(Event)
        stats.category[key].event[balls] = event
    }
    stats.category[key].event[balls].value += 1

    word := ""
    if len(balls) > 1 {
        word = "Balls"
    } else {
        word = "Ball"
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s:%s\tCount:%d\n", word, balls_to_csv(balls), stats.category[key].event[balls].value)
}

func (stats *Stats) digits1(key string, winner []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(winner); i++ {
        stats.record(key, string(winner[i]))
    }
}

func (stats *Stats) digits2(key string, winner []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(winner)-1; i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(winner); j++ {
            stats.record(key, string(winner[i])+string(winner[j]))
        }
    }
}

func (stats *Stats) digits3(key string, winner []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(winner)-2; i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(winner)-1; j++ {
            for k := j + 1; k < len(winner); k++ {
                stats.record(key, string(winner[i])+string(winner[j])+string(winner[k]))
            }
        }
    }
}

func (stats *Stats) digits4(key string, winner []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(winner)-3; i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(winner)-2; j++ {
            for k := j + 1; k < len(winner)-1; k++ {
                for l := k + 1; l < len(winner); l++ {
                    stats.record(key, string(winner[i])+string(winner[j])+string(winner[k])+string(winner[l]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func (stats *Stats) digits5(key string, winner []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(winner)-4; i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(winner)-3; j++ {
            for k := j + 1; k < len(winner)-2; k++ {
                for l := k + 1; l < len(winner)-1; l++ {
                    for m := l + 1; m < len(winner); m++ {
                        stats.record(key, string(winner[i])+string(winner[j])+string(winner[k])+string(winner[l])+string(winner[m]))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func (stats *Stats) digits6(key string, winner []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(winner)-5; i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(winner)-4; j++ {
            for k := j + 1; k < len(winner)-3; k++ {
                for l := k + 1; l < len(winner)-2; l++ {
                    for m := l + 1; m < len(winner)-1; m++ {
                        for n := m + 1; n < len(winner); n++ {
                            stats.record(key, string(winner[i])+string(winner[j])+string(winner[k])+string(winner[l])+string(winner[m])+string(winner[n]))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func balls_to_csv(key string) string {
    s := ""
    length := len(key)
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        s += fmt.Sprintf("%d,", key[i])
    }
    return s[:len(s)-1]
}
```

Comment: You must provide more information. What do you want to achieve using recursion, for example? Why your piece of code is not working?

Comment: If you look at the functions, "digits1() through digits6()" they are similar with more or less nesting and a different string lengths in the record function.  I'm sure someone with more coding experience than me has seen this pattern before and could convert it to recursive function.  I currently have these methods statically written and this is not the best solution. I have written recursive methods before but I can't seem to come up with anything for this. Having a dynamic , possibly recursive digits#() function would make the game more dynamically modifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want to recursively find all the combinations of winning numbers. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func combinations(n []int, c []int, ccc [][][]int) [][][]int {
    if len(n) == 0 {
        return ccc
    }
    if len(ccc) == 0 {
        ccc = make([][][]int, len(n))
    }
    for i := range n {
        cc := make([]int, len(c)+1)
        copy(cc, c)
        cc[len(cc)-1] = n[i]
        ccc[len(cc)-1] = append(ccc[len(cc)-1], cc)
        ccc = combinations(n[i+1:], cc, ccc)
    }
    return ccc
}

func main() {
    n := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    fmt.Println("winning numbers", n)
    fmt.Println()
    nw := 0
    w := combinations(n, nil, nil)
    fmt.Println("winning tickets:")
    d := " digit : "
    for i := range w {
        fmt.Print(i+1, d)
        d = " digits: "
        for j := range w[i] {
            nw++
            fmt.Print(w[i][j], " ")
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(nw, "winners")
}
```

Output:

```
winning numbers [1 2 3 4]

winning tickets:
1 digit : [1] [2] [3] [4] 
2 digits: [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [2 3] [2 4] [3 4] 
3 digits: [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 3 4] [2 3 4] 
4 digits: [1 2 3 4] 

15 winners
```

Simplifying, you can see the recursion.

```
func combinations(n []int) {
    if len(n) == 0 {
        return 
    }
    for i := range n {
        combinations(n[i+1:])
    }
    return 
}
```

The recursion terminates when `len(n) == 0`. In the for loop, `i` increases to `len(n)-1`, `combinations(n[i+1:])` becomes `combinations(n[len(n):])`, and `len(n[len(n):]) == 0`, which will terminate the recursion.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have written recursive functions before but not with as much complexity. Looking at the (<a href="https://play.golang.org/p/-kNjWKOzdZ" code I wrote</a>) it just cry's out for recursion. I'm looking at (https://play.golang.org/p/suoVTWpQvv" your solution) and have no idea what's going on. I will take the time to study it until I do though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not a language specific concept. If you know what is recursion and if you know how to write a function in Go, then you can write a recursive function in Go.

This is a dummy recursive function in Go.

```
func f(n int) int {
    if n < 0 {
        return 0 // or something else
    }
    if n == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return n * f(n - 1)
}
```

This is a recursive function in Go, because,

1. It has a termination (base) condition(n <= 0)
2. f(n) depends on f(x) for all x < n.
3. It's written in Go.